# React Setup 'npm run build' error "unexpected token 'b' at 18:4"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs

Currently using this tutorial: http://www.zsoltnagy.eu/step-by-step-environment-setup-of-the-react-developer-no-legacy-2016-standards/

I thought I followed everything correctly but when I attempt step seven, I get this error (see image).

Here is my package.json file - I will admit I may have changed some things whilst trying to get it to work on my own.

```
{
"name": "rapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "\"\"",
"main": "index.js",
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "\"\""
},
"keywords": [
    "\"\""
],
"author": "\"BH0\"",
"license": "ISC",
"scripts": {

    "test": "\"\""
    "build": "webpack -d && cp src/app/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --colors --progress --content-base src/",
    "build-prod": "webpack -p && cp src/app/index.html dist/index.html"
}
```

}

Thank-you. [Screen-shot of error displayed in Console after entering 'npm run build'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk50N.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add a comma after "test": "\"\""

Answer (score 1):

Your package.json isn't valid. Remove the test entry in the scripts section or add a `,` behind it. Now it should work.

It should be

```
{
"name": "rapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "\"\"",
"main": "index.js",
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "\"\""
},
"keywords": [
    "\"\""
],
"author": "\"BH0\"",
"license": "ISC",
"scripts": {

    "test": "\"\"",
    "build": "webpack -d && cp src/app/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --colors --progress --content-base src/",
    "build-prod": "webpack -p && cp src/app/index.html dist/index.html"
}
```